# How to trans-compile React inside Django project in Pycharm?

Tags: django, reactjs, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm to write a Django App with React as the frontend. Because the React source code is inside the Django source code, there is no clear way to trans-compile the React source code.

I know Pycharm can compile the code if it is a React project, but there are no instructions for compiling if it is embedded in a Django project.

I don't have a list of things I've tried because I have no idea where to start other than doing searches on Google, which I've already done.

I did look at the file-watcher in Pycharm, but it is not clear if this is a solution because there is nothing React related in it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper way to go about this is to have two different projects, one for Django and one for React; you can then attach them later in one window, if you want (just open one, then the other - you will be prompted about what to do with the second).

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to follow a tutorial that embeds it in the Django app. Supposedly, this simplifies the authentication process. DOes this sound true to you?